# How to set sysctl variables at CoreOS cloud-init?

Tags: cloud-init, coreos

I'm looking for a way to set CoreOS `sysctl` settings during its `cloud-init` stage.

The CoreOS version of `cloud-init` only allows for a handful of configuration directives and is not the same as the regular `cloud-init`. For example, there is no `runcmd` section (see http://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/setup/cloudinit-cloud-config/).

`systemd` provides a way to manage `sysctl` settings though files (http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sysctl.d.html). I am using the CoreOS `cloud-init` `write_files` section to create a file at `/etc/sysctl.d/50-nf_conntrack.conf`. But it won't be picked up because the CoreOS cloud configuration happens after the `sysctl.d` configuration has already taken place.

Perhaps I could somehow use another `systemd` unit file to restart the `sysctl.d` unit? How could this be accomplished?

Comment: can you rephrase your question?

Comment: @alexus - it's clear enough to me. What are you having difficulty understanding?

Comment: I added some more context and tried to make it a little more clear (with my specific use case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See answer on CoreOS github issue tracker:
https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/747#issuecomment-142764415

> There might be a simpler way in future, but for now you can simply
>   write a unit to invoke systemd-sysctl during cloudinit; it'll be
>   started after any files specified in write_files are written:
>
> ```
> #cloud-config 
> .... 
> coreos:
>   units:
>     - name: update-sysctl.service
>       command: start
>       content: |
>         [Unit]
>         Description=Update sysctl values written by cloud-config
>         [Service]
>         ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl ...
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the `write_files` actually happens before units.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for others for some tips.

You can do this to run arbitrary commands similar to runcmd.

```
- name: runcmd.service
  command: start
  content: |
    [Unit]
    Description=Runs a command

    [Service]
    Type=oneshot
    ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "touch /etc/environment;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `sysctl` on the file yourself to make the settings take effect immediately, and the configuration file will be used for later reboots (if your instance is persistent).

I'd use a [run command](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/examples.html#run-commands-on-first-boot) for this.

```
runcmd:
- sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/50-nf_conntrack.conf
```

Comment: The CoreOS `cloud-init` has limited keys available, and `runcmd` or `bootcmd` are not in the list.

Comment: Figures they'd do something strange. You might have to force a reboot to get this applied. cloud-init doesn't seem to have any way to start or restart services directly.